# Join Python dictionaries with a matching key:value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary of lists of dictionaries like this:

```
{
    customers:[{customername:"Bob", age:32}],
    addresses:[{customername:"Bob", address:"123 Seseme street",addressname:"home"},
               {customername:"Bob", address:"543 42nd street", addressname:"Work"}],
    phonenumbers:[{customername:"Bob", phone:1234567, phonename:"Cell"}]
]
```

I want to create a new dictionary out of all the other dictionaries that have the key:value pair 'customername:"Bob"':

```
Bob = {customername:"Bob", address:[{addressname:"home",address:"123 Seseme street"},
                                    {addressname:"Work", address:"543 42nd street"}],
       phone:{phonename:"Cell", phone:1234567}
```

First question: How do I create this new dictionary, in the most elegant way possible?

Second question: is there a way to join these for a top-level dictionary that contains some arbitrary number of dictionaries, not all of which will contain that specific key?

Comment: This problem is not particularly complex, it just takes some hard work.  You really need to try writing a solution first and post your attempt if/when you get stuck.  This is not a good place to simply ask for a solution without trying something first.

Comment: Yeah, turns out you were right, it is simpler than it seems on the surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brionius was right, this was easier than it looked at first:

```
l = [[x for x in db[x] if x['name']=='bob'] for x in db]
bob = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist
```

And if I decide to preserve the top-level dictionaries, this works:

```
{key:value for (key,value) in db.iteritems() for item in value if item['name']=='bob'}
```